# Do I need to fulfil an oath made out of anger?

Tags: oaths, anger

I made an oath about a thing in anger. I didn't actually want to make an oath, but my situation and my anger made me do it. My question is: do I need to fulfil the promise, or I can break it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take an oath, you must fulfil it. But in Islam, for an oath to be valid, there are some conditions:

- It has to be taken in Allah's name or his attributes.
- The one taking the oath must be sane and mature. And should do so 
  with free will and clear intention. Similarly, if he takes an oath
  involuntarily, or unintentionally, in a state of excitement, the oath
  will be void.
- The oath is not on something impossible.
- An oath taken must not be for a haraam or makrooh act.
- For a person who is angry, their oath is not valid.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=185570)